# How to get referer action name in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to get the previous action name though previous url already find some how but previous action name is not find yet.
previous url name get like this.

```
$this->getRequest()->getHeader('Referer')->getUri();
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't find action name but I could find like `/controller_name/action_name` using this code

```
$this->getRequest()->getHeader('Referer')->uri()->getPath();
```

It could also be be helpfull for me.

Comment: What is the solution for Zend1?